# VBA/SQL openrecordset(strSQL) Error 3001

Tags: sql, vba

I am trying to run a query on a database server (Oracle 10g) using VBA/Excel and to display the results in a excel table. I have created the ODBC connection (read-only) and tested the connection. I works fine if I import data as a data source in excel (I am able to filter through a query as well) However my VBA code is giving me Error 3001

```
Sub Test()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim canConnect As Boolean
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "DSN=blah;Uid=blah;Pwd=blah"

strSQL = "select job_start_dttm, job_end_dttm from c_job"
Set rs = cnn.openrecordset(strSQL)
ActiveCell = rs(0)

End Sub
```

I get Error 3001 - Arguemnts are of worng type, are out of acceptable range, or are in confilct with one another

The query itself runs fine in SQL developer. Thanks

edit: The error is on "Set rs = cnn.openrecordset(strSQL)" line

Comment: What line are your errors on? My guess would be ActiveCell = rs(0).

Comment: Set rs = cnn.openrecordset(strSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Test()
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim canConnect As Boolean
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

cnn.Open "DSN=blah;Uid=blah;Pwd=blah"

strSQL = "select job_start_dttm, job_end_dttm from c_job"
rs.Open strSQL, cnn
ActiveCell = rs(0)

End Sub
```

You seem to be mixing up a little DAO with your ADODB. You could have used Execute, but the above should suit.

Comment: To expand: If you have both DAO & ADO referenced, you should *always* qualify the library in your Dim statements (don't depend on reference order), and if you get "weird" errors, the first thing to check is that you're using the correct syntax for the library.

Comment: While you should specify the library, it is possible that this would have run if there was no reference to the DAO library, however, the real problem is that `openrecordset` is not a method of the ADODB connection object, so `Set rs = cnn.openrecordset(strSQL)` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Try qualifying the type name of rs with the ADODB prefix to make sure it is not being defined as the built-in Access Recordset object type instead.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
```

**Edit:**

You will also need to use the ADO .Execute command instead of the DAO .OpenRecordset:

```
Set rs = cnn.Execute("...")
```

Comment: Still getting the same error at Set rs = cnn.openrecordset(strSQL)?